# How to add Prefix sparql in axios.get()

Tags: vue.js, axios, sparql

When i  don't add prefix everything fine, but i add prefix the error in console say :

`400 (Parse error: ?      PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns??Encountered " "<" "< "" at line 1, column 19.??Was expecting:??`

This is my code in Vue js :

```
methods:{
getUrl(){
  axios.get(`
  http://localhost:3030/demo/sparql?format=json&query=
  PREFIX    rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
    SELECT *   
    WHERE {
            ?s ?p ?o
    } LIMIT 10 `).then((response) =>{
      this.loading = false;
      const result = response.data.results.bindings;
      this.data = result;
      console.log(result)
    })
}
```

**And here is the error in Console :**

`xhr.js?b50d:178 GET http://localhost:3030/demo/sparql?format=json&query=%20%20%20%20%20%20PREFIX%20rdf:%20%3Chttp://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns 400 (Parse error: ?      PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns??Encountered " "<" "< "" at line 1, column 19.??Was expecting:??    <IRIref> ...??)`

[image: Error in Console]

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please don't post Images of your code, just post them here aswell as your error message, if possible. Please consider reading the [ask] section of our [help] and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: The query string has to be URL escaped: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI .

Comment: And your clearly using axios not like you should. You can specify the params separately with `axios.get('http://localhost:3030/demo/sparql', {
    params: {
      query: ...    }
  })`

Comment: Thnks @AKSW, that's work for me